# Getting data in the respective columns

Tags: soql

I need to retrieve this specific columns with their expected data values from SOQL resultset when I execute the following SOQL query

> select SI_Old_Product_ID__c
>   , Name,
>    (Select Name
>         ,SKU_MAP_Price_Amt__c
>                          from SKUs__r)
>   from SI_Product__c
>   WHERE CreatedDate > 2013-10-08T01:02:03Z

[Sample Data from the query above when executed][1[image: ]]

How can I optimize the data coming from a subquery so that it can appear in its respective columns like

Name                               SKU_MAP_Price_Amt_c 
200696-01                           19.99

I am using the Sales force input step in Pentaho.

Please help me.

Comment: Where are you running this soql ? I think it's a display issue of the tool you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do with the resulting data?  Are you importing the SKU records to another database (or salesforce instance)?

I don't have much to go off from your question, but one simple way you could "optimize" the query above is to tackle it from the Child (SKU object) rather than the Parent (SI_Product__c).  Here's an example of what I mean:

```
Select 
    SI_Product__r.SI_Old_Product_ID__c
    ,SI_Product__r.Name
    ,Name
    ,SKU_MAP_Price_Amt__c 
From 
    SKU__c 
Where 
    SI_Product__r.CreatedDate > '2013-10-08T01:02:03Z'
```